# Creating an async event inside a dataTable column and rendering a button according to response

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, async-await, datatables

I am using dataTables to represent a list of institutions. One of the columns in the table has button to check API status, so when a user clicks it will say if the API is active or inactive. I have this working but now I will like to make it an async event so when the page or the dataTable is loaded we get the status of the API after few seconds automatically, how can I achieve this as I am unable to find anything useful regarding this. Below is my code.

```
 $.ajax({
    url: '/getInstitutionsList',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function(response) {
        var institutionsTable = $('#institutionsTable').DataTable({
            responsive: true,
            data: response.data,
            language: dataTableLang,
            columns: [
                { data: null, defaultContent: '' },
                { data: 'description' },
                { data: 'email' },
                { data: 'phone' },

                {
                    data: null,
                    render: function (data, type, row) {
                        
                        if (locale === 'fr') {
                            return "<button class=\"btn button-status btn-primary btn-sm ml-4 mb-2\"  id= 'checkApiStatus" + data.id_institutions + "' data-instituteid='"+ data.id_institutions +"'> "+ frLocaleDataTable['CHECK API STATUS'] + " <i id='spinner" + data.id_institutions +"' class=\"fa fa-spinner fa-spin hidden\"></i></button>"
                        } else {
                            return "<button class=\"btn button-status btn-primary btn-sm ml-4 mb-2\"  id= 'checkApiStatus" + data.id_institutions + "' data-instituteid='"+ data.id_institutions +"'>Check API Status<i id='spinner" + data.id_institutions +"' class=\"fa fa-spinner fa-spin hidden\"></i></button>"
                        }

                    }

                },
                {
                    data: null,
                    render: function (data, type, row) {
                        return " <button class=\"button-expire btn-sm ml-4 mb-2\" style=\"border:none;\" data-instituteid='"+ data.id_institutions +"'><i class=\"fa fa-clock\"></i></button>"
                    }
                },
                { data: 'id_institutions' },
                {
                    data: null,
                    render: function (data, type, row) {
                        return " <button class=\"button-manage btn-sm ml-4 mb-2\" style=\"border:none;\" data-instituteid='"+ data.id_institutions +"'><i class=\"fa fa-pencil-alt\"></i></button>"
                    }
                },
                {
                    data: null,
                    render: function (data, type, row) {
                        return " <button class=\"button-delete btn-sm ml-4 mb-2\" style=\"border:none;\" data-instituteid='"+ data.id_institutions +"'><i class=\"fa fa-trash\"></i></button>"
                    }
                }
            ],
            columnDefs: [
                {
                    targets: [6],
                    visible: false,
                    searchable: false
                },
                {
                    targets: [0],
                    checkboxes: {
                        selectRow: true
                    }
                }

            ],
            select: {
                style: 'multi'
            },
            pageLength: 5,
            order: [[ 1, 'asc' ]],
            bDestroy: true,

        });

    }

});
```

Below is the event on button with button-status class click

```
 $('.button-status').click(function (e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var instituteId = $(this).data('instituteid');
        $('#spinner' + instituteId).removeClass('hidden');
        $.ajax({
            url: '/getInstitutionStatus/' + instituteId,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response) {
                $('#spinner' + instituteId).hide();
                document.getElementById('checkApiStatus' + instituteId).classList.remove('btn-primary');
                document.getElementById('checkApiStatus'  + instituteId).classList.add('btn-success');
                document.getElementById('checkApiStatus'  + instituteId).innerText = 'Active';


            }, error: function (e) {
                $('#spinner' + instituteId).hide();
                document.getElementById('checkApiStatus'  + instituteId).classList.remove('btn-primary');
                document.getElementById('checkApiStatus'  + instituteId).classList.add('btn-danger');
                document.getElementById('checkApiStatus'  + instituteId).innerText = 'Inactive';
                $("#overlay").fadeOut(2000);
                document.getElementById('errorDiv'  + instituteId).innerHTML = '<p class="p-3">' + e.message + '</p>';
            }
        });

    });
```

Here is the screenshot of the dataTable with the buttons for reference
[image]

Answer (score 2):

According to DataTables reference there is a callback option you may want to use:
**initComplete**
https://datatables.net/reference/option/initComplete

> It can often be useful to know when your table has fully been
> initialised, data loaded and drawn, particularly when using an ajax
> data source. In such a case, the table will complete its initial run
> before the data has been loaded (Ajax is asynchronous after all!) so
> this callback is provided to let you know when the data is fully
> loaded

So you may add it as an option to your 'SUCCESS' response for 'getInstitution' call... somewhere here:

```
var institutionsTable = $('#institutionsTable').DataTable({
                responsive: true,
                data: response.data,
                language: dataTableLang,
                initComplete: function(settings, json) {...}
```

Comment: this actually worked, you have to append your data, in the dataset using row.data() and it will then redraw the table